# Is the sentence meaningful without context?

Tags: grammar

Is the following meaningful without context? Can it be called a sentence? As for me, it is a sentence and meaningful because 'am' means 'exist'.

> I am.

Comment: With no context at all it would be regarded as a strange or even silly sentence, but it is nevertheless a grammatically complete sentence, for the reason you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

It is a grammatically correct sentence and it means, as you say, 'I exist'. Whether that is ever WORTH saying - without context - is a different matter. **In** many contexts it would be well worth saying but, since we take it for granted that each of us IS, to say "I am" out of the blue would be pointless.

But as 'being-ness' is a problem central to philosophy, your sentence is much discussed in that realm, particularly in response to Descarte's "I think therefore I am" of 1637. If you were to say "*I am*" in the company of philosophers they might ask you how you *know* you are.